# How can I give a table column name as "limit" in Postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.3, alter-table

How can I give a Postgres table name as "limit"? When I tried with phpPgAdmin interface it works properly.

But when tried through pg console it fails. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`limit` is a reserved word and therefor requires quoting in order to be used as an identifier:

```
create table some_table
(
  some_column integer, 
  "limit" integer
);
```

More details about identifiers and their naming rules are in the manual
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Note that quoted identifiers become case **sensitive**! 
`"LIMIT"` is a different name than `"limit"` or `"Limit"`

---

It is usually not a very good idea to use reserved words or any name that requires quoting (or quoted identifiers in general). In the long run they are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: Oh sorry , i actually needed "limit" as a column name

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich: column name, table name - same rules.